# Passing variable amount of parameters to a template class

Tags: c++, templates

Example:

```
template <class T>
class Wrapper
{
public:

        Wrapper() { Wrapee = new T; };
        ~Wrapper(){ delete Wrapee; };

    T*  operator->() { return Wrapee; };    

private:

    T*  Wrapee;
};
```

Now we get this:

```
Wrapper<ClassA> WrappedA;   //ClassA's constructor does not take arguments, so this is ok.
Wrapper<ClassB> WrappedB;   //ClassB's constructor needs arguments, error.
```

Is there a mechanism that would allow passing a variable list of arguments to the constructor of the wrapped class ?
(I know this is a silly example, it's just to make the point clear)

Comment: Make the wrapper constructor a variadic template function and use [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic example for perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename... Args>
Wrapper(Args&&... args) :
  Wrapee(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}
```

Note: I advise you to use a smart pointer instead of a raw one (or instead of `Wrapper` in the first place).